# Deserialize JSON with varying element names

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm struggling deserializing an json into an vb.net object with newtonsoft. The problem is, that the element name of the following array is different for each array:

```
{
    "ABC": [{
            "key": "123",
            "md5sum": "e24cb0e730269e419f036a10dd6c38d0",
            "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["3162"],
            "document_index_start": ["3147"]
        }
    }, {
        "key": "456",
        "md5sum": "e24cb0e730269e419f036a10dd6c38d0",
        "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["3162"],
            "document_index_start": ["3156"]
        }
    }
],
"UZT": [{
        "key": "074",
        "md5sum": "dfed620a43ed7dcc2f0923337b9a75b0",
        "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["92"],
            "document_index_start": ["85"]
        }
    }
],
"NEQUZ": [{
        "key": "651",
        "md5sum": "8b7bf4c2477ec72e0577aa5c968ffa1c",
        "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["3686"],
            "document_index_start": ["3663"]
        }
    }
],
"NUTRF": [{
        "key": "8422",
        "md5sum": "a730b1bf89fd4da9986edeb931f3e507",
        "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["1133"],
            "document_index_start": ["1117"]
        }
    }, {
        "key": "5488",
        "md5sum": "a7aaff53e54d252ede34139e2f2404a1",
        "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["1154"],
            "document_index_start": ["1151"]
        }
    }, {
        "key": "5522",
        "md5sum": "a7aaff53e54d252ede34139e2f2404a1",
        "entity_metadata": {
            "document_index_end": ["1163"],
            "document_index_start": ["1156"]
        }
    }
]
}
```

How can I deserialize this particular json to an vb.net object? I'm struggling about the different names of the following arrays, like "ABC", "UZT".

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards
Martin

Comment: Deserialize to a Dictionary<String, T> where the key is "ABC", "UZT"...

Comment: Thank's Plutonix! And if I dont know the "key"? Have I to read them before? Thei have always other values...

Comment: The deserializer is going to create the Dictionary, not you.  Are you actually trying to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost always map the data to a `Dictionary(Of String, T)` where the key/string will be the property name and the `T` is a class to hold the data.  With a simple property, that could be string, int, date etc.  It would be ideal for this sort of thing, but `T` would be a class.  The classes:

```
Public Class ItemData
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property md5sum As String
    Public Property entity_metadata As EntityMetadata
End Class

Public Class EntityMetadata
    Public Property document_index_end As String()
    Public Property document_index_start As String()
End Class
```

If you use a robot to make these (such as in Visual Studio: ***Edit*** menu, **Paste Special**, **Paste JSON as classes**), there is a bit of cleanup to do.  The robots are not terribly clever so they make `Entity_Metadata1`, `Entity_Metadata2` etc.  Since the make up is identical, you can distill it to just one.

Another thing is arrays.  They will create:

```
Public Class Entity_Metadata###
    Public Property document_index_end() As String
    Public Property document_index_start() As String
End Class
```

But the correct syntax ought to be `...As String()`  Then deserialize:

```
Dim items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, ItemData()))(jstr)

' test/proof:
' the As... is important so that the Value gets cast correctly
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, ItemData()) In items

    Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, MD5: {1}, ndx end {2}",
                      kvp.Key,
                      kvp.Value(0).md5sum,
                      kvp.Value(0).entity_metadata.document_index_end(0))
Next
```

Results:

> key: ABC, MD5: e24cb0e730269e419f036a10dd6c38d0, ndx end 3162
>   key: UZT, MD5: dfed620a43ed7dcc2f0923337b9a75b0, ndx end 92
>   key: NEQUZ, MD5: 8b7bf4c2477ec72e0577aa5c968ffa1c, ndx end 3686
>   key: NUTRF, MD5: a730b1bf89fd4da9986edeb931f3e507, ndx end 1133

In practice, since `ItemData` is an array as are the `index` props, you may want or need to test the length.

Comment: Hei, it works fine! The type of string has been the solution..
Thank you very much :)
Best regards, Martin

Comment: Yeah, I used c# syntax in the comment without thinking